# Is there any WYSIWYG html editing tool or component that allows Format Copying from a paragraph to another?

Tags: html, wysiwyg

I believe the question says it all ... (I'll update if needed)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.openwebware.com/

Comment: no safari/chrome support

Comment: Do you know for sure? How does one copy the format??  Their demo does not work with Firefox 3.1.  (The sales part looks very good though)

Answer (score 1):

[FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.com/) can do the job.